# Finding a strings in a text using regular expressions with Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have a text, in which only `<b>` and `</b>` has been used.for example`<b>abcd efg-123</b>` . Can can I extract the string between these tags? also I need to extract 3 words before and after this chunk of `<b>abcd efg-123</b>` string.
How can I do that? what would be the suitable regular expression for this?

Comment: obligatory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handles tags inside the `<b>` unless they are `<b>` ofcouse.

```
import re    
sometext = 'blah blah 1 2 3<b>abcd efg-123</b>word word2 word3 blah blah'
result = re.findall(
      r'(((?:(?:^|\s)+\w+){3}\s*)'            # Match 3 words before
      r'<b>([^<]*|<[^/]|</[^b]|</b[^>])</b>'  # Match <b>...</b>
      r'(\s*(?:\w+(?:\s+|$)){3}))', sometext) # Match 3 words after

result == [(' 1 2 3<b>abcd efg-123</b>word word2 word3 ',
    ' 1 2 3',
    'abcd efg-123',
    'word word2 word3 ')]
```

This should work, and perform well, but if it gets any more advanced then this you should consider using a html parser.

Comment: this doesn't work if there is no words before or after, or less that 3 words, right?

Comment: @Hossein That's correct. However it is a simple change. Change {3} to {,3}

Answer (score 3):

this will get what's in between the tags,

```
>>> s="1 2 3<b>abcd efg-123</b>one two three"
>>> for i in s.split("</b>"):
...   if "<b>" in i:
...      print i.split("<b>")[-1]
...
abcd efg-123
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a very dumb version and doesn't allow nested tags.

```
re.search(r"(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+<b>([^<]+)</b>\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)", text)
```

[See Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.search).

Answer (score 0):

You should not use regexes for HTML parsing. [That way madness lies.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

The above-linked article actually provides a regex for your problem -- but *don't* use it.